# How correctly to handle Secrets in Angular Apps, so the secrets do not get exposed to end user?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm currently integrating a monitoring solution for my Angular Frontend app. TO do that, the monitoring provider requires a script to be present in the index.html. However, that script contains sensitive data such as API_KEY, LICENSE_KEY, etc.

**My Question is:** What is the best & secure way to handle those secrets?

Thanks in adavance

**My current idea** is to inject those secrets into the script in the build proccess to avoid having them hardcoded in the commited code.

Comment: The secret will still be visible in the dev tools. You can't really do anything to hide it

Comment: If the data is sent to the user in any form, it's possible for them to get it. Avoiding committing the secrets is good for separate reasons, but won't have any advantage here.